# How to adapt a Spyke model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following User spyke model. How can I change the model to have something like `user.company.name`?

```
class User < Spyke::Base

  attributes :name,
             :email,
             :phone,
             :password,
             :errors
end
```

Comment: you can specify association in your models to use. According to your statement you have company model as well. so you can add association like `has_one :company`  in your user model and you can use `User.find(1).company.name`. For more info https://github.com/balvig/spyke

Comment: Thanks Melebius , but can i do that without association .?